# a: hover IE 7 issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, hover

I am trying to have a simple CSS based animation on a button (on hover it should indent like a button being pressed in).  It works in all bowers except IE 7 which we are forced to support.

--------EDIT--------

<s>**THIS IS A SCREENSHOT OF THE ISSUE IN IE 7:
[LINK](https://www.fsb.muohio.edu/fsb/content/programs/international-study/gridcode/bad.png)</s>

This is what is supposed to happen: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/XMBWr/3/)

any help with a fix for IE 7 is appreciated!  thank you!

CSS:

```
  /*itinerary Button Style*/    
    .gallery {
background-image:url(PageImages/hover.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 75px;
width: 200px;
}

.gallery a{
background-image:url(PageImages/Itinerary.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 75px;
width: 200px;
display: block;
}

.gallery a:hover{
background: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
        <a href="http://www.sba.muohio.edu/mis399/student/ScheduleWinterSoutheastAsiaPlanAasdfseoinbxsdfjjdgccc.htm" style="margin-top:10%;"></a>
           </div>
```

Comment: there is nothing related to animation in your code, and nothing related to indenting.. What is the actual problem ? (*what should happen and what happens instead..*)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say that it doesn't work? What happens, and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: Sorry,  It should act exaclty like this: [link](http://www.nucopy.com/), rather I can see both images (the unlicked, and clicked images) in IE 7 overlapping

Comment: [this is what is supposed to happen:](http://jsfiddle.net/XMBWr/3/)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli please check the edits to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, in my opinion, a cleaner solution that will work in IE7 (http://jsfiddle.net/YYUef/1/):

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    /* PageImages/Itinerary.gif */
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/50');
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
a:hover {
    /* PageImages/hover.gif */
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/50/09e');
}
```

You just need to change url images and you are good to go.

Edit: And a better solution, using [css sprites](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/). Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmapT/).

```
a {
    background-image: url('http://i44.tinypic.com/34j3g53.gif');
    display: block;
    height: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -75px;
}
```

Comment: I would like to add: The images should be in a sprite, so the there woulnt be a blank on the first hover.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, the problem is not occuring on the `hover` but in general, the images are mis-aligned..

Most likely a white space issue..

set you html to

```
<div class="gallery"><a href="http://www.sba.muohio.edu/mis399/student/ScheduleWinterSoutheastAsiaPlanAasdfseoinbxsdfjjdgccc.htm" style="margin-top:10%;"></a></div>
```

(*remove the whitespace between the tags*)

---

Also, as @scumah says in his answer, why set the hover as background of the div beneath the link, and not just change the images on the link on `hover` (*and remove it from the `.gallery` element completely..*)?

```
.gallery a:hover {
    background-image:url(PageImages/hover.gif);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

IE7 won't just accept a `display:block` attribute on `<a>` tags. You'll have to force it by applying `zoom:1`.